# Does JPA support Optional<?> as JPA entity properties?

Tags: jpa

I wonder if JPA supports Optional as entity property types? This would make handling of nullable fields nicer.

Comment: The JPA provider I use (DataNucleus) does. But this is always going to be provider specific ... the JPA spec is public for you to check for yourself

Comment: Nicer? IMHO Optional should not be used in Java Beans. Read this article: https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/optional-in-java-se-8.html